# In linear regression, what is the difference between performing variable selection before assessing multicollinearity or vice versa?

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, linear-model, multicollinearity

If you have a number of variables you're interested in and want to perform linear regression, is there a clear preference between:

Method A.

1. Perform variable selection techniques (e.g. using stepwise AIC/BIC)
2. Remedy multicollinearity

Method B.

1. Remedy multicollinearity
2. Perform variable selection techniques
3. (Potentially remedy multicollinearity again if necessary)

Note: The technique I'm familiar with for 'remedying' multicollinearity is removing one variable at a time (if necessary) by looking at variance inflation factors.

Answer (score 0):

In linear regression, multi-collinearity problem leads to *unreliable coefficients and corresponding p-values*. Therefore if p-values are used to do step-wise variable selection/elimination, then you have to remedy multi-collinearity first before taking the decision to select or eliminate a variable.